Large working model of water flow and cloud formation on the table, powered by infrasonic transducers - presented at UNFCCC Climate Summit
Large working model of water flow and cloud formation on the table, powered by infrasonic transducers - presented at UNFCCC Climate Summit 2019
My Dear Friends,
as I recall correctly I watched large working model of water flow, clpoud formation on the desk, powered by infrasonic transducers, during Climate Summit New York 2019 UNFCCC
I have saved web link, bookmarked it.
In the meantime I moved to modern computer, get web links easily from Internet search engine, searching for water cycle working model presentation on the desk (images).
My computer crashed, so I moved to another one, which failed run windows on an old disk.
So I have lost my bookmarks, web links, saved web pages.
Tried hard to get web link to the only large scale, working model of water cycle, cloud formation, powered by a number of infrasonic transducers but failed.
Spent some days and still no chance to find the right web link.
But the large, live water cycle presentation on the table, in Ne York at UN HQ during UNFCCC Climate Summit is the only of this kind in the world and I need to study it for cloud seeding.
I am sure few of you have visited the same water cycle working model presentation (large scale on the table) in the past and can share the correct web link with me.
Please help me since my Internet search for water cycle working model and alike search terms, generated thousands of images but none pointing me to the correct one, from the past (2019)
thank you
best ragards
darius
BTW
In the meantime I have contacted UN staff at New York via email, via Twitter and no help, no reply

My Dear Friends,
I can access hundreds of Water Cycle images via Internet search engines but none represents the only, very large physical, working presentation of the Water Cycle, Cloud Formation on a large table, powered by infrasonic transducers built into the table
Can you help me ?
